# Is there a "wordpress-ideas like" opensource web software?

Tags: wordpress, forum

I'm looking for a web platform to set up a forum where users can post and vote "ideas" (i.e., proposals about a topic).

More specifically, I need something like [Wordpress Ideas](http://wordpress.org/extend/ideas/).

Anybody knows any opensource software which could help me?

kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, WordPress ideas is powered by bbPress + plugins + custom theme.

You probably could spend some time and accomplish a similar set up with some forum software of your choosing, a voting plugin, and some custom theming.

Comment: Thank you, what if I try directly with bbPress?

Comment: You could definitely achieve the same effect with bbPress, though I would recommend a different forum software at the moment. bbPress appears to be dying and there are more feature-filled products out there. Check out [Vanilla](http://vanillaforums.org/) or maybe [phpBB](http://phpbb.com/).

Answer (score 1):

[IdeaTorrent](http://ideatorrent.org/) is a GPL licensed written in PHP, SQL, and Drupal that will run a site that allows users to vote on idea. I haven't used it, but am looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm building something similar to that in rails: https://github.com/Chocksy/opiniodev-rails-app

I just started right now but i intend to work on it each week. If you are interested any contributor is welcomed.

I'm going to make a blog session tutorial of how i build this thing also.